# Read a file from inside of an external Jar file?

Tags: java, file, jar, external

I'm trying to read a file from inside an external jar using java..
For example, I have two jar files. One is "foo.jar" the other is "bar.jar". Inside of "bar.jar" is the file "foo-bar.txt". How do i read the file "foo-bar.txt" from inside of "bar.jar" using code in "foo.jar"...? Is this even possible..? 
I know that i can read a file from iside of foo.jar using

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("foo-bar.txt");
```

But I don't know how to do it from an external jar.. can someone help me?

Comment: does `bar` provide a way to access this file? if so, add it to the build path of `foo` and use the appropriate objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use jar url to open connection the example code

```
InputStream in = null;
String inputFile = "jar:file:/c:/path/to/my.jar!/myfile.txt";
if (inputFile.startsWith("jar:")){
  try {
    inputURL = new URL(inputFile);
    JarURLConnection conn = (JarURLConnection)inputURL.openConnection();
    in = conn.getInputStream();
  } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    System.err.println("Malformed input URL: "+inputURL);
    return;
  } catch (IOException e1) {
    System.err.println("IO error open connection");
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208999/how-can-i-retrieve-information-from-text-file-using-java-streams/13209144#13209144) information could be helpful for file IO.

Answer (score 5):

If the jar is in your classpath then `getResourceAsStream` will work, but note that it will find the *first* instance in your classpath. If foo.jar and bar.jar both contain this file then it will return whichever jar is first in classpath.

To read it from the jar use [`JarFile.getEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getEntry%28java.lang.String%29) and [`JarFile.getInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#getInputStream%28java.util.zip.ZipEntry%29)

Comment: Would I do that like this?

`JarFile j = new JarFile("bar.jar");`
`j.getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo-bar.txt");`

Comment: No. You would need `j.getEntry` and `j.getInputStream`

Comment: Could you show me some code? (I learn best from code snippets)

Comment: @Roman's (answer)[http://stackoverflow.com/a/13294687/18573] is better and has example, but I confess I believe there is enough information in my answer to not need actual code. Have you done any programming before?

Comment: Quite a bit. But very little java.