# Running .jar file within JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, jar

I'm trying to develop a website that takes user input and converts to a text file. The text file is then used as an input for a `.jar` file. (e.g. `java -jar encoder.jar -i text.txt`), the jar then outputs a `.bin` file for the user to download.

This jar is designed to be run from command line and I really don't know the best way to implement it within a `.jsp` page. I have created a few java test classes but nothing has worked so far.

Does anyone have any suggestions on possible methods?

Comment: Your best bet might be to load the jar into your site and run it in process - you'll probably just have to replace the main class. Do you have source for the .jar? If not you could try decompiling the main class to see how complicated this is. You might need to be careful that the code releases all resources correctly though i.e. it doesn't just assume that everything gets released automatically on termination since if you call in yourself from your JVM then the JVM it's running in won't then be terminated. Alternatively you can probably find a different implementation - what's the encoding?

Comment: Thank you that is an interesting idea, i hadn't thought of that. Basically the .jar file I am using is not my own so im not sure about its encoding. Its used to convert the text file to hex so it can interpreted by a piece of hardware. I will try to decompile the .jar file later and see if that would be a workable method. In the mean time if anyone else has any ideas they are welcome...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to running it as an external process is to invoke its main class in the current JVM:

1. Extract/open `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` of the jar
2. Identify the [`Main-Class:`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html). Say it is called `EncoderMainClass`
3. Invoke its `main` method: `EncoderMainClass.main("-i", "text.txt")`

This aught to be faster because a new OS process does not need to be created, but there may be security considerations.

Comment: This worked perfectly, managed to pass the arguments in through the main class and generate the .bin files. By security considerations what exactly do you mean, could the user attempt some form of overflow? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Read up on [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html). The class would have different security policies applied when it is running on command line v/s running within your app server context. Since it is working, my guess is you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried somrthing like this,

Create a java file

use a `ProcessBuilder` and start a new JVM.

Here is something to get you started:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/path/to/java", "-jar", "your.jar", "thetextfile.txt");
pb.directory(new File("preferred/working/directory"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

ps: do handle to destroy process else it will eat up all memory

Answer (score 0):

You can put this jar to the web application on the *classpath* and use it's class and methods. Better if you have *javadoc* if you don't have sources. But even if not in `classpath` you can try the [example](http://javabender.blogspot.com/2012/07/urlclassloader-and-reloading-class-from.html) or [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294594/read-a-file-from-inside-of-an-external-jar-file/13294687#13294687).